# WPF datagrid data refresh

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I'm doing a WPF(MVVM) dashboard apparently DevEx controls (yet to decide) , before starting I want to get clarification on few questions.

Q1: For developing dashboard screen with a grid that displays some graphics which datagrid to choose, native WPF datagrid or any other 3rd prty like DevExpress controls ?

Q2: how to make datagrid refresh the data changes that are made at database side. I will get the data with datareader from model and bind it to grid. I don't want the user to worry about refreshing the screen by clicking button or some other control event, any changes made to data should be refreshed to the grid without user intervention. The changes made to the database by other external systems but not by the GUI of this application.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In your model expose delegate or event, when ever value changes,your model will be knowing. so, in that case you can simply call that delegate or the event

In your ViewModel, have private method and hook that method to the delegate or the event of the model.

When ever Model invokes the delegate or event, that method that in the viewModel that is hooked will get called, in that method, you can again the query the database and update the property that is Binded to the View, which will automatically refresh the view(UI)

Comment: Kumareshan, how does my model know that any changes have done to database? once model knows then your suggestion works to communicate to VM and V hence forth, but my question still lies between DB and Model.

Comment: I assume that only Model updates the DB. Correct me if i'm wrong. is there any other external source updating DB. If so make every thing go via Model, then your job will be very easy

Comment: No, my model is not updating the DB, another external system updates the DB.

Comment: In that case as a work around you can have Thread in the model which keeps on Checking the status of the DB, and notifies the Viewmodel when ever there is a Change in DB. This is not recommended since Thread is costly operations and which does nothing in your case other than checking the status of DB, if you find any other better solution please go head with that other wise you can do this work around

Comment: Any thoughts on which control to choose? Does a native datagrid provide flexibility of adding gfx etc

Comment: Ya you can chose native datagrid. And it depends on your requirement how you want to show to the user. or you can use Items control also